# How to display the eager loaded value

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

My eager loaded query result looks like below. I wanted to know how I can display the value for a specific `specValue`.

For example, the `specification_id` is 9 and it has a specific value. But not for all models. So this array would be available only for some models.

```
BrandModel {#295 ▼
  #table: "models"
  #searchable: array:2 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:6 [▶]
  #original: array:8 [▶]
  #relations: array:4 [▼
    "pivot" => Pivot {#294 ▶}
    "brand" => Brand {#385 ▶}
    "specValues" => Collection {#2139 ▼
      #items: array:19 [▼
        0 => SpecValue {#2142 ▼
          #table: "specification_values"
          #connection: null
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #perPage: 15
          +incrementing: true
          +timestamps: true
          #attributes: array:9 [▶]
          #original: array:9 [▼
            "id" => 9
            "specification_id" => 9
            "model_id" => 1
            "value" => "2,400,000 impressions"
            "filtered_value" => "2,400,000"
            "created_at" => "2015-12-31 16:47:11"
            "updated_at" => "2015-12-31 16:40:52"
            "name" => "max monthly duty cycle"
            "title" => "Monthly Volume"
          ]
          #relations: []
          #hidden: []
          #visible: []
          #appends: []
          #fillable: []
          #guarded: array:1 [▶]
          #dates: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #casts: []
          #touches: []
          #observables: []
          #with: []
          #morphClass: null
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
        }
        1 => SpecValue {#2143 ▼
          #table: "specification_values"
          #connection: null
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #perPage: 15
          +incrementing: true
          +timestamps: true
          #attributes: array:9 [▼
            "id" => 18
            "specification_id" => 18
            "model_id" => 1
            "value" => "2,000 sheets"
            "filtered_value" => "Single 2,000 Sheet Paper Drawer"
            "created_at" => "2015-12-31 16:47:11"
            "updated_at" => "2015-12-31 16:40:52"
            "name" => "std paper capacity"
            "title" => "Std Paper Capacity"
          ]
          #original: array:9 [▶]
          #relations: []
          #hidden: []
          #visible: []
          #appends: []
          #fillable: []
          #guarded: array:1 [▶]
          #dates: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #casts: []
          #touches: []
          #observables: []
          #with: []
          #morphClass: null
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
        }
        2 => SpecValue {#2144 ▶}
        3 => SpecValue {#2145 ▶}
```

Right now I check like this:

```
<li>Speed B/W: @foreach($model->specValues as $spec) @if($spec->name=='Monthly Volume'){{$spec->value}} CPM @endif @endforeach </li>
```

But this seems not right. How can I do this?

I tried this also:

```
{{$model->specValues()->where('specification_id', 227)->first()->filtered_value}}
```

But if there is no specification id such as 227 for a model, then I get error saying that trying to access non property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `keyBy()` function to organize a collection based on a particular key:

in blade:

```
$specs = $model->specValues->keyBy('title');

@if(isset($specs['Monthly Volume'])

  {{$specs['Monthly Volume']->value}}

@endif
```

Comment: If `$specs['Monthly Volume']->value;` is not present for a model, then it returns error `undefined index`..